# how can I configure a simple eventlistener on symfony

Tags: symfony, addeventlistener, event-listener

``I tried to add an event listener on a field of a formular, but it doesn't work at all ; a var_dump on the variable gives allways the value "null", whatever I can do.
Is there something to do in the folder services.yaml, or some javascript to add somewhere ?
I'm total beginner, but I love this project and I would really like to succed in it.

```
       ->add('tournamentGame', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'oui'=>true,
                    'non'=>false,
                ],
                'data'=>true,
                "attr"=>[
                    'class'=>'ms-2',
    
                ],
                'multiple'=> false,
                'label'=>'Mode Tournoi',
                'mapped' => true,
                'required' => false
            ])
        ;
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $tournamentGame = $event->getData();

                $multiplayer = $tournamentGame->isTournamentGame();
                $nbTotalPlayer = null === $tournamentGame ? [] : $multiplayer;
                $choice = false === $multiplayer ? ['2 joueurs'=>2,
                    '4 joueurs'=>4,
                    '6 joueurs'=>6,
                    '8 joueurs'=>8,
                    '10 joueurs'=>10,
                    '12 joueurs'=>12,
                    '14 joueurs'=>14,
                    '16 joueurs'=>16,
                    '18 joueurs'=>18,
                    '20 joueurs'=>20,] : 
                [];

                $form->add('nbTotalPlayer', ChoiceType::class, [
                        'label' => 'Nombres de joueurs',
                        'choices'=>$choice,
                                            
            
                     ]);
                     var_dump($multiplayer);
            }
        );
```

I've joined this jquery to the template, In the console I can see that the variable tournament has the correct values, but I need  to return it into the the form in php, maybe it would be easier for you to understand what I want to do, I have to change the part with function(html), but I don' know what I can replace it with.

```
<script>
var tournamentGame = $('#game_tournamentGame');
// When sport gets selected ...
tournamentGame.change(function() {
  // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
  // Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
  var data = {};
  data[tournamentGame] = parseInt(tournamentGame.val());
  // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
  console.log(data[tournamentGame]);
  $.ajax({
    url : $form.attr('action'),
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    data : data,
    complete: function(html) {
      // Replace current position field ...
      $('#game_nbTotalPlayer').replaceWith(
        // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
        $(html.responseText).find('#game_nbTotalPlayer')
      );
      // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

[dd($tournamentGame)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D00FF.jpg)

Comment: Hello, what is the goal of your listener? Add a new field if another field have a specific value?

Comment: Just for kicks, try adding `if (!$tournamentGame) return;`   It may or may not help but for some reason some of the events get sent twice.

Comment: @Cerad, hello, can you tell me where I have to write the instruction you gave to me. I have tried to put it at different places that maked sense for me, but it gave nothing.
But thank you for your help

Comment: @Skuti, yes, if $tournament is true, a new field comes where you can set the number of player.
Thank you for your help

Comment: What gives you `dd($tournamentGame);` right after the `$tournamentGame = $event->getData();`? Please show the displayed result. Here is an official way to do this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: `$tournamentGame = $event->getData(); if (!$tournamentGame) return;` It might not make any difference.

Comment: @Skuti I've joined an image of what you asked me to do,
I have already read the doc you sent, that's on it I have based what I have done, I probably didn't really understand how it work

Comment: @Cerad It's different, I've an error message which said the variable multiplayer isn't defined

Comment: Sometimes change is good.  Now try `$multiplayer = $tournamentGame->isTournamentGame(); dd($multiplayer);` and see what happens.  At some point though you might need to step back and maybe implement an example from the docs just to understand what is going on.  I have the feeling that you are not really getting the `big picture`.

Comment: @Cerad it gives the result "null", and yes I'll test the examples from the docs

Comment: Ok, I need to use javascript

Comment: @juliendanne I don't see your picture

Comment: @Skuti I've joined the picture again

Comment: after having seen the docs again I've finally succeed but using javascript was easier.
thanks for trying to help me